# Using CloudFlare CDN with Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, cloudflare

I am trying to use CloudFlare CDN with Azure Blob Storage. I set up a cname on cloudflare pointing cdn.mydomain.com to mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net. and set the status to "DNA and HTTP Proxy (CDN)"

If I then go to mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/news/image.jpg in the browser the image is loaded, but if I go to cdn.mydomain.com/news/image.jpg I receive the follow error message from azure

```
<Error>
  <Code>InvalidUri</Code>
  <Message>The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server. 
    RequestId:aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa Time:2017-04-25T13:20:20.8658692Z
  </Message>
  <UriPath>http://cdn.mydomain.com/news/image.jpg</UriPath>
</Error>
```

Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After configured the CNAME record in your domain provider, you also need to set the custom domain in Azure portal.

Open your storage account -> Custom domain tab

[image]

Comment: This worked. I also had to temporarily turn off HTTP Proxy on cloudflare on that specific cname record and set the cname record to just DNS only while doing the verification on the azure portal. After it was verified I could turn it back to DNS and HTTP Proxy (CDN)

Comment: Wow, turning off HTTP Proxy in cloudflare really helped, I've spent a whole day trying to fix it, thank you @JohnCoder!

Comment: To turn off HTTP Proxy, tap the CNAME's orange cloud to turn it gray. At first this didn't work (error when trying to verify), but when I tried 15 minutes later it worked.

Comment: It is still broken to turn of the proxy because if you deploy with an ARM template, then it will fail, if you haven't turned it off before deploying.

Comment: The Custom domain page is now under Security + networking / Networking.